# printing ArrayList using jstl in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

Using an `ArrayList` of type `Countries` that is a bean class I'm getting only a blank page as output when using the following code:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Countries> countryList = (ArrayList<Countries>) request.getAttribute("al");
%>

<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.code}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  need not to set in request attribute again.You can use below code

```
<c:forEach items="${al}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.code}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

**This way you can get rid of scriptlet also.**

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the EL (Expression language) can't find any variable named countryList in any valid scope. The variable declared in the scriptlet is not visible to the EL so you must add it to a valid scope for example the request so:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Countries> countryList = (ArrayList<Countries>) request.getAttribute("al");
    request.setAttribute("countryList", countryList);
%>

<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.code}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: there is no need to set list once again in request attribute as its already there in request scope.